# Does multivariable quantile regression model with mixed effects require fractional polynomials for independent variables?

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression, glmm, quantile-regression, fractional-polynomial

Hello Cross Validated community,

I am currently working on a project involving **a multivariable quantile regression model with mixed effects**, where the objective is to explore the relationships between several independent variables and a dependent variable, taking into account clustering within the data (e.g., observations grouped by account ID). My dataset involves variables that might exhibit non-linear relationships with the dependent variable, and I am considering using fractional polynomials (FP) to model these potential non-linearities.

I have a few questions regarding the incorporation of FP into my analysis:

1. **Necessity and Appropriateness**: Is it necessary or beneficial to use fractional polynomials in a multivariable quantile regression model with mixed effects to capture non-linear relationships? How does the incorporation of FP impact the interpretation and performance of such models?
2. **Implementation Guidance**: If FP is advisable, how should one go about incorporating fractional polynomials into this type of model? Are there specific considerations or steps that need to be taken to effectively integrate FP with quantile regression and mixed effects?
3. **Base Model for Testing FP**: Before applying FP to the quantile regression model with mixed effects, is it recommended to test the FP transformations on a simpler model first, such as a linear regression model or a basic quantile regression model without mixed effects? This could help in identifying significant non-linear relationships without the added complexity of mixed effects.
4. **Recommended R Packages**: Which R packages would you recommend for implementing fractional polynomials in the context of quantile regression with mixed effects? I am aware of packages like *lqmm* for quantile regression with mixed effects and *mfp* for fractional polynomials in linear models, but I am unsure how to combine these approaches or if there is a better alternative.

Any insights, experiences, or advice you could share on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Spline functions are a little more general than FPs (they allow x=0 or negative) and are used very easily with all regression models.